# split a mathematical expression into components

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing a commandline calculator which, if I don't fudge it, will have fancy things like natural expression evaluation. I want an efficient method of splitting the input expressions into their components for easy evaluation, regardless of if tokens are separated by spaces or not.

even expressions like this should be processable-

```
2x^5 + 6d - h
```

For example,

```
2x^5+2y^4-62
```

would be split into

```
2
*
x
^
5
+
2
*
y
^
4
-
62
```

and then will be evaluated. I made an attempt at this, but it is very messy and ultimately doesn't work. Please give me a few hints on how to tokenise my input with the stl.

Comment: well, obviously i would convert to postfix, but it's the splitting into a list that's bothering me.

Comment: What you're talking about is normally called "tokenizing" or "lexing". You don't typically tokenize an entire input stream, then process it. Rather, you get tokens from the input one at a time, and process them as you retrieve them. One typical approach is greedy tokenizing--that is, based on the first character of the token, you identify what kind of token it is (e.g., number, identifier, or operator). Then, based on that you continue to add characters to the token until you get a character that can't possibly be part of that token.

Comment: Then, could I say I'm having problems with the tokenisation part?I don't know how to get tokens one at a time.

Comment: You could--and if you do some googling on that, you'll probably find quite a bit about how to build (for example) a finite state machine to handle the problem.

Comment: right, my implementation is exactly like that. I iterate through the input string, set a mark at a character, identify the type of token (variable, constant, operator) and set a flag, then continue until the first character which isn't of the same type, then cut out the substring from the mark to the previous position and store it on the stack.

Comment: ah, so state machines are an approach?

Comment: Yes--probably the most common approach to this problem (in fact, you're probably implementing a state machine right now, just without knowing it, so it's probably kind of messy and hard to recognize).

Comment: For a calculator app I'd probably write a [recursive descent parser](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)  - also look into [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

Comment: will do. Recursive descent parsers are a little abstract, but if i get my head around them, I think my code will be very efficient.